# Вместо нескольких записей по критерию выводит только первую

Tags: c, строки, сравнение, вывод

Добрый вечер!

Сделал проверку строк, но дальше он не выводит, только самую первую строку.
То есть, мне надо, что бы он вывел **всех** с городов *Tallinn* и *Tartu*.

Вот не получается сделать. Буду признателен за помощь!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 10
#define Sort1 "Tallinn"
#define Sort2 "Tartu"

struct data { //Personal data structure
    char name[21]; //Name of person
    int mphone; //Mobile phone of person
    struct ads { //Structure of Address
        char street[101]; //Street address
        char city[101]; //City
    } stads;
};

//Function prototypes
    int readData (char[], struct data[]); //Read file
    int resCity (char[], struct data[]); //Residents of Tartu

//Function to Read Data from file.
    int readData (char fname[], struct data st[]) {

    FILE *fopen(), *fData;
    int size=0;
    if((fData=fopen("F1.txt", "r")) == NULL){
        printf("Error oppening file F1.txt");
        exit(1);
    }

    while((fscanf(fData, "%s %d %s %s", st[size].name, &st[size].mphone, st[size].stads.street, st[size].stads.city)) == 4) {
        if(size == N) break;
        size++;
    }

    return size;
    fclose(fData);  
}

//Function to find residents of Tallinn and Tartu
    int resCity (char fname[], struct data st[]) {
    FILE *fopen(), *fData;
    int size3=0;
    int k=0;
        if((fData=fopen("F2.txt", "w")) == NULL){
            printf("Error oppening file F1.txt");
            exit(1);
        }

    //Residents of Tallinn
    printf("\n\nResidents of Tallinn:\n");
        while(strcmp (st[size3].stads.city,Sort1)!=0)
        {
            size3++;
        }

    puts(st[size3].stads.city);
    fprintf (fData, "%s %d %s %s\n", st[size3].name, st[size3].mphone, st[size3].stads.street, st[size3].stads.city);

    //Residents of Tartu
    printf("\n\nResidents of Tartu:\n");


        while(strcmp (st[size3].stads.city,Sort2)!=0)
        {
            size3 ++;
        }

    puts(st[size3].stads.city);
    fprintf (fData, "%s %d %s %s\n", st[size3].name, st[size3].mphone, st[size3].stads.street, st[size3].stads.city);

    return size3;
    fclose(fData);
}

int main(void) 
{
    FILE *fData;
    char fname[21];
    struct data st[N];
    int i;
    int i3;
    int size=0;
    int size3=0;

    size=readData(fname, st);

    for(i=0; i < size; i++){
        printf("%s %d %s %s\n", st[i].name, st[i].mphone, st[i].stads.street, st[i].stads.city);
    }

    size3=resCity(fname, st);

    return 0;
}
```

Файл F1.txt

```
Artur 0000000 Vaikne Keila
Aleksander 1111111 Ehitajate Tallinn
Aisel 2222222 Paekaare Tallinn
Aleksandra 3333333 Pae Kunda
Sergei 4444444 Kunsti Narva
Misha 5555555 Jaama Tartu
Dmitri 6666666 Pae Tartu
Konstantin 7777777 Paekaare Tallinn
Roman 8888888 Linnamae Tallinn
Hennadii 9999999 Jaama Tartu
```

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых зачем вы объявили о некой **новой** функции `FILE *fopen()`, не принимающей параметров? У меня лично ваш код из-за этого не скомпилировался, уберите.

Во вторых ваш файл не закроется, после `return` код в функции не выполняется.

```
return size3;
fclose(fData);
```

В третьих - почему вы решили, что ваш код будет выводить всех, где строка совпадает? Вы находите первого, для которого это так и выводите, один раз, вне цикла. Если хотите, чтобы вывод был для всех, нужно его поместить в цикл, который пройдётся по всему массиву.

Comment: А у меня наоборот, без нее не компилится))

Я пробовал добавлять циклы, либо ничего, либо первый, поэтому я уже обратился сюда, не доходит до меня...

Comment: @Yuriy Orlov: Объявление `FILE *fopen()` тут, разумеется, излишне. Однако в языке С оно не объявляет функцию `fopen`, как "не принимающую параметров".  Оно объявляет функцию `fopen`, как принимающую *неизвестное* число параметров. От такого объявления код не может перестать компилироваться.

Comment: мне `gcc` выдал `error: too many arguments to function ‘FILE* fopen()’`